# Is there any point in flagging an invalid answer on an old question that you've also voted to close?

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-to-close

For this question (and, in general, ones like it): [What is a thread pool in C++ and how it is implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474788/what-is-a-thread-pool-in-c-and-how-it-is-implemented/2474797#2474797)

- It's definitely too broad.
- Its accepted answer is definitely a link-only answer.
- It's 4 years old.

It is reasonable to vote to close the question as "too broad", but is it also worth flagging the answer as link-only? If the question is on track for being closed, it seems pointless to add an answer flag to the queue. If the question does not end up being closed (this one probably will, but in the general sense) but the answer is flagged and deleted, then it turns into an unanswered junk question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Good catch, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, definitely flag that particular answer - there is no guarantee the question will be closed. Just because it is the accepted answer that doesn't make it immune from the quality standards.

I can't find a reference for Stack Overflow in particular, but I know that using Wikipedia as your only reference is frowned upon in other SE sites. It's probably something we don't want to encourage - there's a lot of good accurate info there, but there's also crap.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian True - unfortunately there are incorrect accepted answers. All I'm saying is that some sites have taken the attitude that using Wikipedia as your sole reference can be unsafe.

Comment: From my experiences, link only content to Wikipedia is also annoying because of the chance that the text might change and not actually have the answer the person was trying to post by the time one visits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, flag those answers that deserve flagging.

Argument : Well the question will be closed anyway, thus all the answers will disappear too.

Counter : NO, no, no. The close vote review queue has over 120k questions currently. If you only vote to close the question, that means the question could be sitting in the close vote review queue indefinitely. Also, there's a chance that it could be put back out of the close vote review queue and left free in the wild.

The low quality posts queue gets taken care of fast. So if you flag a low quality answer, it will likely be deleted within an hour or quicker. So please vote to close the questions that deserve it, and flag as not an answer/low quality for the answers that deserve it; no matter if they are on the same page or not.